# query Syntax Error Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to set the

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT Sequence No,Catalog Number,PO Number,Assignee,Customer Name, Marketing Sales Mgr, Notes, Rating Information From Catalog Number Log 2 WHERE Catalog Number Like '34*' ORDER BY Sequence No"
```

but it is giving me a Syntax error. Any ideas why. Any help would be appreciated.A screen shoot of the table is shown below.

[image: Table Catalog NUmber Log 2]

Comment: Use ```[Sequence No]``` where column name contains spaces. Catalog Number etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT [Sequence No],[Catalog Number],[PO Number],[Assignee],[Customer Name], [Marketing Sales Mgr], [Notes], [Rating Information] From [Catalog Number Log 2] WHERE [Catalog Number] Like '34*' ORDER BY [Sequence No]"
```

You have white spaces in your table and column names hence they have to be put in brackets `[ ]` .